why _meansurement is a member of g2o::BaseEdge?How to understand it in theory of graph optimation?
I'm learning about the source of the g2o
and find it both exists _meansurement in BaseEdge<D,E> and _estimate in BaseVertex<D,T>.And _meansurement is as a oberservations of one vertex from other vertexs.
In my opinion,edge is used to describe the prior between the vertexes it attaches to,and the _meansurement shouldn't be as a member of the edges.Why does g2o implement like this?
Can you help me understand it?
